# Source for the practice of messianic interpretation of calamity

Tags: tanach, midrash, rashi, messiah, current-events

I seem to recall a Rashi somewhere in Nach which explains a Pasuk as praising B’nei Yisrael, who see every calamity that befalls them as heralding Mashiach.
Can anyone source this?